# Page Load Firing two times

Tags: asp.net

in my asp page that is content page associated with a master page.In content page IsPostBack value coming false at very first time of page load but when i clicking the button on content page ,then isPostBack giving fasle value that supposed to true how to fix this. any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read This Blog[ASP.NET double-postback bug strikes again!](http://ddkonline.blogspot.com/2008/02/aspnet-double-postback-bug-strikes.html)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have an empty img/background-image url in your page. Please check and correct that by using 'url(none)' or by remove that tag/style.